# It's possible to create power rails in KiCAD?

Tags: kicad

I'm starting with KiCAD and I have a little question about power rails. I know that there are a huge number of power rails by default, but I want know if I'd create my own custom power rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create it as a new symbol and check the "Create Symbol As A Power Symbol" box in the setup dialog.